# What is the Jacobian matrix of Newton's law of gravity?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, vector-fields

I am trying to come up with the gradient of a vector (Jacobian matrix) for Newton's Law of Gravity. In other words, the differential gravitational field in 3-dimension. Here's the initial Law.

$$\mathbf{F} = \frac{MmG}{\mathbf{\lvert x|}^3}\mathbf{x}$$

Separated into its components.

$$\mathbf{F} = \frac{MmGx}{{(x^2+y^2+z^2)}^{3/2}}\mathbf{i}+\frac{MmGy}{{(x^2+y^2+z^2)}^{3/2}}\mathbf{j}+\frac{MmGz}{{(x^2+y^2+z^2)}^{3/2}}\mathbf{k}$$

Defining the magnitude of the x-component, y-component, and z-component as $F_x$, $F_y$, and $F_z$ respectively.

Jacobian matrix as follows:

$$J =\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\dfrac{\partial F_x}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial F_x}{\partial y} & \dfrac{\partial F_x}{\partial z} \\
\dfrac{\partial F_y}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial F_y}{\partial y} & \dfrac{\partial F_y}{\partial z} \\
\dfrac{\partial F_z}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial F_z}{\partial y} & \dfrac{\partial F_z}{\partial z} \\
\end{array}\right)$$

Taking the partial derivative of the gravitational force components with each variable, the magnitudes as follows:

\begin{align}
\dfrac{\partial F_x}{\partial x}&=\frac{MmG(-2x^2+y^2+z^2)}{{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{5/2}}}\\
\dfrac{\partial F_x}{\partial y}&=\frac{-3MmGxy}{{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{5/2}}}\\
\dfrac{\partial F_x}{\partial z}&=\frac{-3MmGxz}{{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{5/2}}}\\
\dfrac{\partial F_y}{\partial x}&=\frac{-3MmGyx}{{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{5/2}}}\\
\dfrac{\partial F_y}{\partial y}&=\frac{MmG(-2y^2+x^2+z^2)}{{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{5/2}}}\\
\dfrac{\partial F_y}{\partial z}&=\frac{-3MmGyz}{{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{5/2}}}\\
\dfrac{\partial F_z}{\partial x}&=\frac{-3MmGxz}{{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{5/2}}}\\
\dfrac{\partial F_z}{\partial y}&=\frac{-3MmGyz}{{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{5/2}}}\\
\dfrac{\partial F_z}{\partial z}&=\frac{MmG(-2z^2+x^2+y^2)}{{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{5/2}}}
\end{align}

Would adding the x-components, y-components, and z-components be the form of the differential gravity? In other words, the gradient of the gravitational vector field?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do. Why do you form a Jacobian matrix out of something that is not a coordinate transformation? What is the "gravitational vector field"? A *gradient* is of a *scalar field*, not a vector field.

Comment: I haven't looked at this in detail, but wouldn't it be easier to calculate the gradient along a specific axis, say $x$.  Then $F_y$ and $F_x$ are zero.  No loss of generality, as the $x$ axis can be chosen to point in any direction.

Comment: To first post, you can take the gradient of a vector field. I thought the same thing earlier since that's all we ever did in Calc III, never gradient of vector. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient#Gradient_of_a_vector

Comment: To second post, that's pretty much what I did. I took the partial derivative for one of the directions (regarding the other variables as constant). Then the other 2 directions are just a matter of moving the variables.

Comment: $\partial_j x_i/x^3 = \delta_{ij}/x^3 - 3 x_i x_j / x^5 $.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: The Jacobian is also used for the gradient of a vector (defined as $\nabla\mathbf F=\partial_if/\partial x_j$). Seems to me OP wants us to check their work though, which makes it off-topic.

Comment: @ACuriousMind For a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$, the differential $df$, written in coordinates, coincides with the Jacobian $\partial_j f_i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing (apart from a minus sign) the tidal tensor, which is the traceless part of the Hessian of gravitational potential, for a point mass in the origin. This tensor contains information about the piece of gravitational force which can't be removed by choosing a free falling reference frame. I'm not sure to understand your problem, however the tidal tensor is, as you can check, symmetric and traceless. So, it is an irreducible tensor. The trace is automatically zero as you can check (if not, it would be a scalar). Also the antisymmetric part is zero (if not, it could be mapped to a vector).
You can't obtain a quantity with reasonable physical properties by adding its components. The relevant object is the tensor itself.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying what I was doing, because I didn't know. Never studied physics past physics 2, and so I had no clue what to look for (tidal tensor). I was just trying to see if the differential force of gravity causing tides can be computed for personal mental therapy. I see now it makes no sense adding components.